# azure api gateway integration with AKS 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: azure, terraform, api-gateway, azure-aks

I am in process to integrate Azure API gateway with AKS.
in order to achieve this.
i had

- created AKS cluster with advance networking. consider it is in
  aks-vnet
- created different vnet for API gateway.
- peer both vnet i.e. vnet for aks and for api gateway.
- created internal load balancer. by
  running azure voting app yaml file also added annotation for using
  internal load balancer

  metadata:
    name: azure-vote-front
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
- added kubernates internal load balancer public ip in address probe of api gateway.

when i navigate in browser with public ip address of api gateway or dns name associated with api gateway i am getting following error

*502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.*

Comment: does your service work if you bypass the application gateway and talk directly to the load balancer?

Comment: @GaneshPol Any update or any more question?

Comment: i find azure api management service is much better than api gateway as it provide me better facility and i am able to work with azure api management service.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is something wrong described in your case: You should provide add the kubernetes internal load balancer private IP to the application gateway backend pool.

Then I did the test as the steps in [Integrate Application Gateway with AKS cluster](https://rinormaloku.com/prohibiting-direct-access-microservices-aks/). As the error shows that **you should make the check if the application in the AKS works fine**, in your case the application is azure voting app.

If you follow the Azure Kubernetes Service tutorial and push the image to Azure Container Registry, you must grant the AKS permission to access your ACR. See [Authenticate with Azure Container Registry from Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?toc=%2Fazure%2Faks%2Ftoc.json).

And on my side, I can access the azure voting app from the public IP of the application gateway. Hope this will help you.